# Excel database formula

Tags: excel, database, formula

Have more then 200k rows and want sort it via multiple criterias.  COUNTIF works perfectly but at the end waiting minutes for simple changes becouse there is more then 1500 formulas.

So i desided for database formulas, but have a problem with criteria headers.

simple example:

[image]

How i can use same crtiteria table without January row ? for me is only way hot to do that is create criteria with headers again:

[image]

Is there any way how can have one criteria table with multiple rows and using only rows what needed ?

Comment: In the first image, if you want to drag that formula down, you have to lock the rows as absolute with $.

Comment: If i lock the rows, February is counted with January in G4

Comment: Yes, for Feb and later you would have to subtract a growin sum of totals above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract a growing total of DSUMS above the current row.

```
=DSUM(A$2:B$11, D$2, C$2:C3)-SUM(D$2:D2)
```

[image]